# Terraform local variables dependancy in for_each statement

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm using following local variables to pass map of `account_id` and `account_type` to my child module in order to do to create patch manager resources based on account_type from my child module.

```html
 
  locals {
    org_sub_accounts_map = zipmap(module.accounts.account_id, module.accounts.tags_all.*.AccountType)
    org_sub_accounts = [for k, v in local.org_sub_accounts_map : {
      id   = k
      type = v
      }
    ]
  }
  
  module "ssm_patch_manager" {
  source                  = "../../../../modules/aws/cloudformation/stacksets"
  accounts                = local.org_sub_accounts
  account_exception_list  = var.account_exception_list
  regions                 = var.region_list
  stackset_name           = "SSM-PatchManager"
  template                = "ssm_patch_manager"
  parameters              = var.patch_manager_default_params
  parameter_overrides     = var.patch_manager_params_overrides
  stackset_admin_role_arn = module.stackset_admin_role.role_arn
  depends_on              = [module.accounts]
}
```

`local.org_sub_accounts` is something like this:

```html
org_sub_accounts = [
    {
      "id" = "111111111111"
      "type" = "Dev"
    },
    {
      "id" = "222222222222"
      "type" = "Prod"
    },
    {
      "id" = "33333333333"
      "type" = "Dev"
    }
 ]
```

This works fine with all the existing AWS accounts as terraform aware of the accounts IDs. Now the problem is, when I'm creating a new AWS account from `module.accounts`, and running the terraform plan, I get below error:

```html
Error: Invalid for_each argument

  on ../../../../modules/aws/cloudformation/stacksets/main.tf line 25, in resource "aws_cloudformation_stack_set_instance" "stack":
  25:   for_each = {
  26:     for stack_instance in local.instance_data : "${stack_instance.account}.${stack_instance.region}" => stack_instance if contains(var.account_exception_list, stack_instance.account) == false
  27:   }
    ├────────────────
    │ local.instance_data will be known only after apply
    │ var.account_exception_list is list of string with 1 element

The "for_each" value depends on resource attributes that cannot be determined
until apply, so Terraform cannot predict how many instances will be created.
To work around this, use the -target argument to first apply only the
resources that the for_each depends on.
```

I understand this is clearly because terraform doesn't know the account_id when evaluating the locals variables. Can anyone suggest something here to resolve this issue?

Please note, this is already implemented solution. But we came to know after sometime when we try to create a new account. Therefore, any suggestion without major structure changes in the code would be really helpful.

**Update**

`instance_data` is a resource block in child module.

```html
locals {
  instance_data = flatten([
    for account in var.accounts : [
      for region in var.regions : {
        account = account.id
        type    = try(length(account.type), 0) > 0 ? account.type : "default" # To support legacy var.account input, which account 'type' key is not passed.
        region  = region
      }
    ]
  ])

resource "aws_cloudformation_stack_set_instance" "stack" {
  for_each = {
    for stack_instance in local.instance_data : "${stack_instance.account}.${stack_instance.region}" => stack_instance if contains(var.account_exception_list, stack_instance.account) == false
  }
  account_id          = each.value.account
  region              = each.value.region
  parameter_overrides = lookup(var.parameter_overrides, each.value.type, null) # To handle different parameters based on 'AccountType' Tag in sub accounts
  stack_set_name      = aws_cloudformation_stack_set.stackset.name
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the local.instance_data?

Comment: @palvarez I updated the question. There is nothing much came to my mind to try. I just tried by adding different depends_on things. Still no luck.

Comment: Have you tried using ´count´ instead of ´for_each´ structure?

Comment: Thanks for the tip @palvarez. I'm just trying to do that myself. Not sure if count can serve everything what we done through `${stack_instance.account}.${stack_instance.region}` without changing the current state.

Answer (score 0):

Finally came up with below solution. Just posting this here if anyone needs to reference in future.

```html
data "aws_organizations_resource_tags" "account" {
  count       = length(module.organization.non_master_accounts.*.id)
  resource_id = module.organization.non_master_accounts.*.id[count.index]
}


  # “for_each” value in child module depends on resource attributes (AWS account_id) that cannot be determined until terraform apply, so Terraform cannot predict how many instances will be created.
  # Because of this, we use `aws_organizations_resource_tags` data source to create stacksets, instead of module outputs.
locals {
  org_sub_accounts = [for account in data.aws_organizations_resource_tags.account : {
    id   = account.id
    type = try(length(account.tags.AccountType), 0) > 0 ? account.tags.AccountType : "default" # In case AccountType tag missing in existing/invited accounts.  
    }
  ]
}



# Output in Organization module
output "non_master_accounts" {
  value = aws_organizations_organization.root.non_master_accounts
}
```